# Flowchart to loop an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I am currently having a horrible time figuring out how this professor wants this flowchart to look like. This is for a programming class using Python. His assignment descriptions switch back and forth between using Python and other programming languages so I get quite confused. This brings me to our assignment today which asks to:

Create a FLOWCHART and a PSEUDOCODE for each problem.
 1.   Problem 1: Create an array that contains the days of the week.

2. Problem 2: Create a loop to print the content above.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
WeekDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

for Item in WeekDays:
    print(Item)
```

So, I have the code down. I am just struggling with how the flowchart will look. I put the for statement in the diamond but he said it should be "an if or is question" and then the output should be yes or no which does not make sense to me.

Comment: I don't want to be too harsh because you're aware that your question might be bad - but what's the question again? What flowchart for what code? Just for the three lines you provided?

Comment: Yes, he wants a flowchart for the three lines that I provided. Apologies, I will edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Also what's a "flowchart for an array"?

Comment: Maybe he's expecting you to write the loop in a more traditional way, like how it's done in other languages with a loop counter, and break the loop once you have printed every element. We cannot know. At this point the only thing we can tell you is to ask for clarification from your prof.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop you've posted is logically similar to:

```
Is there another item?
If yes, then:
    Get next item as 'Item'
    Print 'Item'
    Go to start of loop
If no more items, exit the loop
```

Formatting this as a flowchart is an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Anything similar like this

```
WeekDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
counter = 0
input_data = 'yes' #Default first yes to give a start for while loop
while input_data == 'yes':
    print WeekDays[counter]
    counter+=1      
    if counter < len(WeekDays) and counter != 0:
        input_data = raw_input("Do you want to proceed with next item?(yes/no)")
    else:
        counter = 0
        input_data = raw_input("Do you want to proceed with next item?(yes/no)")
```